# Free Text Box width limit/wrapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, freetextbox

Hi I use the [Free Text Box](http://www.freetextbox.com/) in my .net application.

I was wondering if there was a way to prevent someone typing one single huge line of text.

Can you set a wrap boundary on it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a short read of the [documentation](http://www.freetextbox.com/docs/ftb3/), and I don't think you'll find a native way to do so.

I guess you could use the `FreeTextBox.TextChanged` event, and check every line in the `FreeTextBox.Text` property. Mind the fact that it is HTML, and you will probably have to parse it with another third party tool (doing it manually will only give you headaches).

If any of these lines has more characters than an arbitrary length you'll set, create a new line of text with the surplus character, and move the caret to this line.

Comment: I will take a look at that